# Update shared styles with JavaScript application wide in Polymer 2.0

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a `shared-styles` element that keeps most of my applications colors.  I can easily change the colors manually in `shared-styles.html`, and all of my other components can inherit from there if I use the CSS variables.

My problem is I need to update the CSS variables in `shared-styles.html` and have all the other components that inherit the CSS variables to update their colors accordingly.  Below is my `shared-styles.html`.  For brevity, I removed all the variables except `--app-primary-color`.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<!-- shared styles for all views -->
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style is="custom-style">
      :host {
        --app-primary-color:#2196F3;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
  <script>
    class SharedStyles extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'shared-styles'; }

      ready(){
        super.ready();
        console.log('update css');
        this.updateStyles({'--app-primary-color': 'red'});
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(SharedStyles.is, SharedStyles);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is how I am including them in the other components.  For example:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shared style is not a Polymer element, so it should not extend `Polymer.Element` and should not have a `<script>` tag. It should be defined like this:

**shared-styles.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<!-- shared styles for all views -->
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --app-primary-color: #2196F3;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Then, call `this.updateStyles` in the root element (e.g., `<my-app>`) to apply a global style in Polymer 2.0. Note that all elements under `<my-app>` would inherit the newly specified styles.

#### Example

Here are instructions using Polymer CLI's `polymer-2-starter-kit` template:

1. Install the bleeding edge Polymer CLI (`npm install polymer-cli@next`), required for the `polymer-2-starter-kit` template.
2. Run:

   ```
   mkdir polymer-2-shared-styles-demo
   cd polymer-2-shared-styles-demo
   polymer init polymer-2-starter-kit
   ```
3. In `src/my-app.html`, add a `<button>` to the menu, which will change the value of `--app-primary-color`:

   ```
   <template>
     <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
       <!-- Drawer content -->
       <app-drawer id="drawer" slot="drawer">
         <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>

         <!-- ****     LINE 77: Add button below      **** -->
         <button on-click="_changeAppColor">Change app color</button>

   <script>
     class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {

       /* ***    LINE 130: Define button-click handler below     **** */
       _changeAppColor() {
         this.updateStyles({'--app-primary-color': 'red'});
       }
   ```
4. In `src/shared-styles.html`, change `.circle`'s `background` to use `--app-primary-color`:

   ```
   .circle {

     /* ***    LINE 33: Use --app-primary-color below     **** */
     background: var(--app-primary-color, #ddd);
   ```
5. Run `polymer serve -o` to open the starter kit in the default browser.
6. Click the button in the menu to change the color of the toolbar and the circles in each page. It should look like this:
   [image: screenshot]

[GitHub project](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/polymer-2-shared-styles-demo/commits/master)